# Bash - How to discriminate control operator from metacharacter?

Tags: bash, shell

According to [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> `control operator`
>
> A token that performs a control function. It is a **newline** or one of the following: ‘||’, ‘&&’, ‘&’, ‘;’, ‘;;’, ‘|’, ‘|&’, ‘(’, or ‘)’.
>
> `metacharacter`
>
> A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a **blank** or one of the following characters: ‘|’, ‘&’, ‘;’, ‘(’, ‘)’, ‘<’, or ‘>’.

Many characters are both `control operator` and `metacharacter`.

So how could I konw the syntax category of e.g. a `;`?

Take `if COND ; then CMD ; fi` as an example.

`;` seems like a `control operator` in the context, for it can be substituted by **newline**.
However removing pre and post **space**s around `;` still works ok.
Isn't it supposed to be separated by sapces if it's an **operator**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the bash manual, an `operator` is:

> A *control operator* or a *redirection operator*. See Redirections,
>   for a list of redirection operators. **Operators contain at least one
>   unquoted metacharacter.**

The metacharacter is basically any character that cannot be part of a `word.`

Definition of `word`:

> A sequence of characters treated as a unit by the shell. Words may not include unquoted metacharacters.

There is no need for spaces around `operators` because they always contain `metacharacters`, which makes the parser know it is not part of the `word`.

An exception is `redirection`, where e.g.

```
ls 2>&1
```

requires a space prior to the redirection statement since the operator has a parameter `2`, and requires the parameter to be next to the operator (otherwise it will be a parameter to `ls`).

Comment: I were miss-thought about `;` as the same as `[`. Now I'm clear, `[` is a command while `;` is an operator. Thanks.